# Oauth2login and JWT

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, oauth2resourceserver

I would like to know how to have both access to my endpoint api with Google(oauth2login) and with JWT (using oauth2ressourceServe)

I already implement solution to access with jwt using the oauth2RessourceServer who validate my token

```
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests-> requests
                        .requestMatchers(requestMatchers).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sm->sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .headers(hs -> hs.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(getCsrfConfigurerCustomizer())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2->oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }
```

And now i don't know how to add oauth2login, because all request will be blocked by oauth2RessourceServer because i don't send jwt as expected by : .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2->oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))

thanks

Comment: where are you getting your token from?

Comment: i generat token after user login. and user send me in the header the token for each request http from my angular app

Comment: you are aware that, that type of implementation is insecure, and that is why you have problems. You should not generate JWTs and hand them out to browsers becuase there is no way of storing a JWT securely in a browser, and using a JWT as a sesison as you are doing makes it so that you cant logout the user. Im guessing you have a read one of the bad blogposts out there. Read the spring security documentation and implement FormLogin instead, and dont use JWTs

Comment: when the user try to login with username and password , i generate a JWT and i send it to the front app, why it is not secure ? even if the user try to modify the jwt he can't access on my api because every request i check the jwt ?

Comment: but what if i steal your JWT through a XSS attack? i get you to run my malicious code that will steal your token and send it to me. How are you planning to stop me then?

Comment: I have to add a refresh token . And then my jwt will be expired in 2min and regenerate an other token. During this 2 min I don’t thinks hacker had time to do something’s

Comment: 2 minutues is going to hurt your performance very very bad when you start getting load

Comment: also what if i steal your refresh token and just issue new tokens for myself over and over?

Comment: So for you what is the solution when using JWT ?

Comment: to only use JWTs for what they were meant to be used for. And that is to authenticate between micro services. And not using a JWT when dealing with browsers, and instead use cookies.